# Issue with inserting node in BST (iterative method)

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

Below is my code for inserting node in BST.
I am facing segmentation fault.I tried to debug with the gdb and found out that it is crashing when inserting second node i.e insert(&root,9) at

```
current->left = newNode(key);
```

Inside while loop in if condition. I am not able to find the root cause.Please help me and tell me what is the issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
 };

struct Node* newNode(int item)
{
  struct Node *temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  temp->data = item;
  temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
  return temp;
}


void insert(struct Node **root_ref,int key)
{
  struct Node *current;
  struct Node *parent;

  if(*root_ref == NULL)
  {
    *root_ref = newNode(key);
  }
  else
  {
    parent = *root_ref;
    while(1)
    {
      current = parent;
      if(current->data > key)
      {
        current = current->left;
        if(current == NULL)
        {
          current->left = newNode(key);
          // break;
          return;
     }
  }
  else
  {
    current = current->right;
    if(current == NULL)
    {
       current->right = newNode(key);
       //break;
       return;
    }
  }
} //End of while
}
 return;
 }

int main()
{
  struct Node *root=NULL;
  insert(&root,10);
  insert(&root,9);
  insert(&root,11);
  insert(&root,12);
  insert(&root,8);
  insert(&root,7);

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to access an attribute of an element, **only if the element is `NULL`** !!

```
current = current->left;
if(current == NULL)
{
  current->left = newNode(key);
  // break;
  return;
}
```

That is why you have a segfault.

You should test if the left attribute is `NULL`. If yes add the new element, else go to left.

```
if(current->left == NULL)
{
  current->left = newNode(key);
  return;
}
else
{
  current = current->left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This while loop

```
while(1)
{
  current = parent;
  //...
```

does not make sense because in the beginning of the loop the pointer `current` is always set to the pointer `parent` that is not changed in the loop.

Also these if statements

```
    if(current == NULL)
    {
      current->left = newNode(key);
      // break;
      return;
 }
```

and

```
if(current == NULL)
{
   current->right = newNode(key);
   //break;
   return;
}
```

also do not make sense because if `current` is equal to `NULL` then the access to `current->left` or `current-->right` results in undefined behavior.

The function is too complicated and overloaded with paartial cases.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node * newNode( int item )
{
    struct Node *temp = ( struct Node * )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    if ( temp )
    {
        temp->data = item;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    }

    return temp;
}

int insert( struct Node **root_ref, int key )
{
    struct Node *temp = newNode( key );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *root_ref != NULL )
        {
            if ( key < ( *root_ref )->data ) root_ref = &( *root_ref )->left;
            else root_ref = &( *root_ref )->right;
        }

        *root_ref = temp;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;

    insert( &root, 10 );
    insert( &root, 9 );
    insert( &root, 11 );
    insert( &root, 12 );
    insert( &root, 8 );
    insert( &root, 7 );

    return 0;
}
```